# Publish on facebook and twitter like instagram

Tags: react-native, twitter, facebook-share, react-native-fbsdk, fbsdksharedialog

I am making a social media app in react native where I want to add feature to publish the post on Facebook and Twitter same as in Instagram.

[image]

As I have gone through many articles and documentation it says that **publish_actions** has been deprecated and we should use Share Dialogs but I don't want that popup coming, it should directly post on Facebook. How to achieve that and how does Instagram does it ?

From Facebook documentations:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried the RN fbsdk share dialogs. That comes with a modal to post on timeline, which I don't want. I went through Facebook documentations but I didn't find anywhere as if how to post directly on user timeline, it allows to post directly on pages but not on a user timeline.